# Responsive fixed <h1> not proportioned to background sample

Tags: html, css

I have to put several images and texts on the site and they should be in the same position as the background image but when I minimize the screen size the proportionality is lost, I tried with an image of the text that I needed and it worked for me but I can not do that work with  texts

Thank you very much for your help i've just been stuck for the hole day trying to find the solution

```
 .title {
   width: 74.5%;
  }
 /*text image png
 .title.s1{
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 36%;

 }
 /*text in h1*/

 h1.title.s1 {
  color: rgb(60, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 34.5%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}


   <div id="r_bg-img">
    <img src="/img/rokubun_background.png"  width="100%">
</div>
<div class="content">
    
    <img src="/img/title1.png" class="title s1" >

    <h1 class="title s1">The premise</h1>

</div>
```

[In the link there's the output  , the gray text is added as an img and the green text is added as a  and below those elements the background titles are in orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqXB2.png)

Comment: Can you explain clearly what do you need to do?

Comment: I need to fix the green <h1>  so it looks like the orange in size and position on every screen size (I tried adding the title as a img and i was able to "position:absolute" and locate it at the correct position ) but it doesn't work when i use <h1> text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your contents propotional, you can use the styles like below.
We can use the `padding-top` property as a percentage to make the gap between your contents like headers and images.

Here this is an example I tried, You can apply the styles properly for our contents. It is easy to create an outer and inner containers to keep the contents like headers and images.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>


.container {
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;/* 1:1 Aspect Ratio */
}

.container .outer {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5%; /* defines aspect ratio */
    position: relative;
}
.container .outer .inner {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 0% 25%;
}

 h1 {
    margin:auto;
  color: rgb(60, 255, 0);
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <h1 class="inner">Your content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <img src ="https://www.pngmart.com/files/13/Tetris-PNG-Free-Download.png">
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <h1 class="inner">Your content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <img src ="https://www.pngmart.com/files/13/Tetris-PNG-Free-Download.png">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can follow this to get an idea [https://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements#:~:text=For%20proportional%20resizing%20purposes%2C%20it,the%20aspect%20ratio%20you%20need.&text=And%20that's%20it](https://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/12/10/very-simple-css-only-proportional-resizing-of-elements#:%7E:text=For%20proportional%20resizing%20purposes%2C%20it,the%20aspect%20ratio%20you%20need.&text=And%20that%27s%20it)!

Hope this will help you and think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you @Sandushi ! so finally I achieved it. In order to mantain the proportion of the text elements i had to put the "font-size" in 'vw' instead of %. And after that I've just positioned the element as an absolute. Thanks for your time!